# PYTHON: How do i calculate the correlation matrix of a data frame without using pandas or numpy?

Tags: python

I want to calculate the correlation matrix of my data frame, without using pandas.corr() or numpy.corrcoef(), if this possible?

Comment: Python doesn't even _have_ matrices or dataframes. Pandas does, though. If you have a dataframe, you're using Pandas (or some other library). Asking how to do anything with matrices and dataframes without Pandas doesn't make sense.

Comment: i just want to do calculation without libraries, not make the data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why are you trying to do it however you can use the following formula to create one function.
THe below image is Pearson correlation coefficient
xbar is the mean of x,y bar is the mean of y

[image]